# Setting summary to describe the current value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I'm trying to set summary when the users select a preference item, it normally saved. But when my app is restarted, the summary is gone.

Here is my code to set the summary for `ListPreference` and `EditTextPreference`:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){

    Preference pref = findPreference(key);

    // I feel the problem is happened here
    if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
        pref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    }
    // Same problem here
    if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editText = (EditTextPreference) pref;
        pref.setSummary(editText.getEntry().toString());
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: you should set the summary even in oncreate

Comment: What about the parameter? This parameter [SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key] is associated with Preference pref = findPreference(key). In onCreate, this parameter (String key) is not available.

Comment: if it is not, then add android:key in the xml

Comment: But I have added android:key for every preferences in the xml.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set edittext preference summary and have it stick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651653/how-to-set-edittext-preference-summary-and-have-it-stick)

Answer (score 27):

if you only want to show the current entry, try to set the summary in your xml:

```
android:summary="%s"
```

This works only for the `ListPreference` (see [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#getSummary%28%29)):

> If the summary has a String formatting marker in it (i.e. "%s" or "%1$s"), then the current entry value will be substituted in its place.

Answer (score 7):

The problem might be that [the listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) is not called on startup (the value is not changed). But you can set the summary dynamically in the XML. For a `ListPreference`, this is built-in and [@FreshD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116856/1587329) is the way to go. To extend to an `EditTextPreference`, you need to create your own class. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083261/1587329)

> ```
> package your.package;
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.util.AttributeSet;
>
> public class EditTextPreference extends android.preference.EditTextPreference{
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>             super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>         }
>
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>             super(context, attrs);
>         }
>
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context) {
>             super(context);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public CharSequence getSummary() {
>             String summary = super.getSummary().toString();
>             return String.format(summary, getText());
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> And use this in your xml:
>
> ```
> <your.package.EditTextPreference
>                 android:key="pref_alpha"
>                 android:summary="Actual value: %s"
>                 android:title="Title"
>                 android:defaultValue="default"
>                 />
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
 ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("listkey");
 listPref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());

 EditTextPreference editText = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("edittextkey");
 editText.setSummary(editText.getEntry().toString());
```

If you have the key then set the summary like above, in oncreate after addpreferences in your preferenceFragment or Activity

Answer (score 2):

I struggled so much to make summaries dynamic. Not exactly sure if this answers the question but wanted to post somewhere so if someone searches they don't have to struggle like i did.

This is the simple solution `useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"`